# SVN 'bad URL Passed to RA Layer' and eclipse project to resetup as svn resource

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am facing a very strange problem. I installed the server and also successfully created branch and put the code in SVN. THen checkout that project in one project as a folder. Now what happened after my PC restart I opened eclipse without starting svn. Some popup came out abt repository not found in eclipse. I closed that window. Now i started SVN. But to my strange I found that the src is there in eclipse project but it is not in sync with SVN. How can i do that as I am not able to view the previsous versions as well. Also direct on the server I am not even able to diff the file with previosu version as it gives some 'Bad URL passed to RA Layer'

Comment: So what exactly happened? :)

Comment: Bad URL sounds like a wrong URl you gave to the SVN command...can you show the commands you have given ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs when the svn version of the code space is deleted knowingly or unknowingly. I encountered the same error message when trying to merge changes to a non existent version(which I had deliberately deleted previously as it was a duplicate branch).

Unknown action received: commit finalizing
    Bad URL passed to RA layer
svn: URL 'svn://svnserver.testdev.com/java/SpringHibernateExample/branches/SpringHibernateExample_With_Annotation' non-existent in revision 55198

To verify the file/folder being referenced is correct:

1. Switch to svn perspective
2. Navigate to the location coming up in error message (eg. java/SpringHibernateExample/branches/SpringHibernateExample_With_Annotation)

You will most likely notice that there is no file/folder at the path being referred and this will allow you to use the correct the location.